# Prevent auto html entities in wordpress

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress, apache

Apache 2

Php 5.2.9

Mysql 5.077

Wordpress 3.5.1

After I installed wordpress, I chose a theme named 'Sliding Door'. Then, I turned to write a front page. After I finished it and pressed 'Publish', the raw html content suddenly turned into html entities, just like this:

When edit in Text Editor, not Visual Editor:

```
This is an example page.It might say something like this: <blockquote>
```

After press 'Publish', still in Text Editor:

```
This is an example page. It might say something like this: &lt;blockquote&gt;
```

This also happened when I wrote **Posts** and **Text Widget**, like some global configures preventing me to submit html codes. It always converted my content into plain text automatically. So weird.

Is there something wrong with the apache? Or something wrong with php? Or something wrong with Wordpress? Or with Mysql?

Comment: did you check how data is stored in database? is it with htmlenties encoded or decoded?

Comment: Can you check and post  meta content-type must be in your header file of your theme...it should be html " <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />"

Comment: Yeah, the data in Mysql are also '&#XXX;' stuff. Obviously, it had been converted before it was saved.

Comment: check your db characterset.. if its other thn utf8 than change it to utf8 also you need to add define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'); in your config file..

Comment: @Rikesh The meta tag in header.php of the theme is "<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />". But after I changed it into what you wrote and redo the submit, it still not worked.

Comment: @Rikesh You're right, most of my Mysql DB's charset related variables are 'latin1', while my DB_CHARSET in wp-config.php is 'utf8'. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the solution. It was the php filter that changed my content. To solve it, I just changed the '**filter.default**' variable in **/etc/php.ini** from '**special_chars**' to '**unsafe_raw**', and then restarted httpd.

Answer (score 0):

So you're not filtering your input at all right now? That's risky. I would filter everything even if I were the only user of the blog/application.

I don't know how Wordpess works but try and set your default editor from WYSIWYG to HTML if you prefer using HTML code. Or allow more HTML tags in the editor. See for example: http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/killer-hacks-to-enhance-wordpress-editor

You could also try [Pure HTML plugin](http://www.hitreach.co.uk/wordpress-plugins/pure-html/).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I'll rethink about it.